# Receiving blank post data with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, paypal-ipn

I'm developing a simple cart with Laravel 4 and Paypal.

For the IPN Listener I've installed the following package:
- https://github.com/mike182uk/paypal-ipn-listener

I created a route with Route::any() allowing paypal to use any method on the request calling to a function with this simple code:

```
    $listener = new \PayPal\Ipn\Listener;
    $verifier = new \PayPal\Ipn\Verifier\CurlVerifier;
    $ipnMessage = \PayPal\Ipn\Message::createFromGlobals();

    $verifier->setIpnMessage($ipnMessage);
    $verifier->setEnvironment('sandbox'); // can either be sandbox or production

    $listener->setVerifier($verifier);

    $listener->listen(function() use ($listener) {
        // on verified IPN (everything is good!)
        $resp = $listener->getVerifier()->getVerificationResponse();
        $report = $listener->getReport();

        $myfile = fopen("ipn.log", "w");
        fwrite($myfile, $report);
        fclose($myfile);

    }, function() use ($listener) {
        // on invalid IPN (somethings not right!)

        $report = $listener->getReport();
        $resp = $listener->getVerifier()->getVerificationResponse();


        $myfile = fopen("ipn.log", "w");
        fwrite($myfile, $report);
        fclose($myfile);
    });
```

When I see the log file Paypal return INVALID, and I see that I dont receive any post data.
But when I use IPN with a single php file with this code from Paypal github I receive all the data.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/master/paypal_ipn.php

P.S: I don't get any error, the IPN is sent successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because I had a csrf filter for al routes.

I solved it introducing this route in a group and adding this code to app/filters.php

```
// CSRF For routes outside "rest" route group.
$firstSegment = Request::segment(1);

if($firstSegment != 'rest')
    Route::filter('csrf','post');
```